# What could be causing these cracks?

Tags: drywall, walls, wood, ceiling, cracks

My partner and I noticed these cracks in part of our wall/ceiling, above where the house juts out for 3 windows (I believe this is called a bay window setup?).

The wall feels dry and doesn't flex/feel spongy, and it's only this section. I'm wondering if it's nails failing to hold up the piece of wood running across where the cracks are, the other side has trim so I can't see anything.

[image: Picture of cracks]

Is there anything anyone can recommend to help me identify the cause and remedy?

EDIT: Additional Photos[image: Photo from further away in bad lighting]

Comment: larger picture would be useful. That being said: how old is that framing? How old is the paint?

Comment: Unknown on both, the house was built in 1961 and we got the house in 2022. I believe the previous owners put on a fresh coat of paint during their stay from 2018/2019 to 2022. I would assume the framing is original to the house.

Comment: bad corner bead install or framing dried out after corner bead was installed.

Comment: With a bad corner bead install, what is the usual process for fixing? I've never heard of  corner bead but googling shows it's a metal frame you install on the corner of drywall? Is the resolution removing and replacing or is there a simpler remedy?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the window was not installed properly, or that the framing shifted and cracked along the corner bead. The "proper" solution is to re-do the drywall work (sanding down the paint and re-doing the mud, then paint over). But if the framing is still unstable, then the crack will re-appear.

Another solution is installing window trim to hide the crack. Especially since you have wooden boxed beams, you can try finding matching trim for the window

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's most likely cause by either 1: settling, 2: seasonal humidity changes, or 3. poor workmanship.

I'd reach out to previous occupants if possible to find out of that is recent work. It probably is.

Just went through this with a home built in the same time frame... major renovations. The simple fact is the structure changes seasonally, with similar cracks growing and shrinking with the seasons. (Michigan)

The best recommendation would be trim to hide it.

Comment: If it was diagonal cracks, I'd say settling. Otherwise I'd go with #2 or #3; cosmetic issue but nothing to worry about.